# How submit nested objects with nested forms gem using link_to_add button?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a inventory system (or something alike), thing is there is a process where user must add 'detail' for 'invoice', in this detail it must substract the added product from the inventory, this is easy to do by calling a before_save method in the 'detail' model, only thing I want to know is how to submit detail everytime the link_to_add button is pressed!

Answer (score 0):

Cocoon(https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) has some callbacks you could to do that. In that particular case, you could use `after-insert`:

```
 $('#container').on('cocoon:before-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
    // ... do something
  });
```

You could catch that to send a request to an action that would do what you desire. 
But anyway, it seems to me that it doesn't has to be executed right before the user add the nested detail. If you put it on `before_save` callback, when you submit the form, it should be executed anyway (even if the form is for the parent model).
Guess this helps you somehow